# Difference quotients uniformly bounded in Holder space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have trouble with proving the following:

Let $u \in C^{k, \alpha}$. For each $h > 0$, denote the 
difference quotient of u in the $j$-direction as $\delta_{h, j}u$. That is, 
\begin{equation}
   \delta_{h, j} u (x) = \frac{u(x + h e_j) - u(x)}{h}.
\end{equation}
Suppose $| \delta_{h, j} u |_{k, \alpha} \leq M$ uniformly in $h$. 
Then $D_j u \in C^{k+1, \alpha}$ and $| D_j u |_{k+1, \alpha} \leq M$.

The Sobolev space version of this argument is easy because we can take a weakly convergent subsequence and pair it with test functions to obtain existence of a higher derivative. However, in the Holder space case, we do not have any test functions to make our lives easy. So I suspect we have to use certain Arzela-Ascoli type compactness, but somehow I am stuck and cannot proceed.
I would really appreciate it if somebody could give me some idea or proof. 
Thank you!

Comment: Is $k$ equal to zero? The assumption has nothing to do with higher order derivatives. And with Holder continuity as well (except for $\alpha = 1$).

Comment: This doesn't look right.  Maybe the conclusion should have $k-1$ instead of $k+1$?